# mutate check for each row slower as "which"

Tags: r, performance, dplyr

trying to check for each row if `position` is between `start` and `end`. If that's the case keep the values in column `A` & `B`

```
df<-data.frame(
  position=c(1,15,250),
  start=c(16,10,200),
  end=c(100,150,300),
  A=c("A","A","A"),
  B=c("B","B","B")
)

#slow
df2 <- df %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(A = ifelse(between(position,start,end),A,NA)) %>%
  mutate(B = ifelse(between(position,start,end),B,NA))

#fast
df$A[-which((df$start < df$position & df$position < df$end))]<-NA
df$B[-which((df$start < df$position & df$position < df$end))]<-NA
```

I need to do that for ~ 50 columns and 22million rows. The `mutate` takes  approx 10 minutes, `which` only needs seconds. I would guess its caused by the `rowwise`, but how could I improve?

Comment: How about discarding `rowwise` and replacing `between(...)` with `start < position & position < end`

Comment: Beat me to it @DarrenTsai, I was going to suggest: `df %>% mutate(across(4:5, ~ifelse(position > start & position < end, .x, NA)))`. Given the size of the data, a data.table solution will probably be worth looking into

Comment: @Darren and jared Thanks! Solved the speed problem. I was somehow hooked on the between thing. skipping this and thereby skipping the rowwise solved the problem.  +1 for the across solution 50lines = 1 line :)